# FFMPEG - create video in with images and video file

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I am creating video using ffmpeg
I have some images and video so i want to create video with images and also video
in node js

my code

```
 ffmpeg()  .addInput(__dirname + '/test/fixtures/step_%1d.png')
 // .outputOptions(['[0:v]scale=200x200'])

 .complexFilter([
     // 'scale=640:480[rescaled]',

     {
         filter: 'zoompan',
         options: {
            x: '200',
             y: 'ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)',
             z: 'min(zoom+0.0005,1.5)',
            d: '125',
             s: "200x200",

         },
         // "inputs":'[0:v]scale=200x200'
     },
 ])

 .format('mp4')
 .videoBitrate('1024k')
 .videoCodec('mpeg4')
 .output(finalVideoPath)
 .on("error", function (er) {
     console.log("error occured: " + er.message);
 })
 .on('end', function () {
     console.log('Finished processing');
 }).run();
```

I want to add video , how we can do in this code, Please help me

Comment: Any solution ? I have used videoshow library in node js but in this we can add only images.

Comment: can we do fade in and fade out with images ?

Comment: Yes. See [Create video with 5 images with fadeIn/out effect in ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/834035/110524) and [concatenating with crossfade several videos (with audio)](https://superuser.com/a/1350872/110524). I don't know anything about node.js so I can't comment on that aspect.